# zpl file size increased while taking a print

Tags: zpl, printers

While I am printing a ZPL label from a .zpl file the print size has increased from 1KB to 17MB what might be the reason for that[image]

Comment: Can you post somewhere the file content? How are you sending the file to the printer, from a software?

Comment: No, it is through command prompt commands

Comment: Please add the ZPL content to your q.

Comment: ^XA
^COY,0^MMT^MTT^MD+0
^XZ
^XA
^PR12^FS
^FO50,50,0^GB750,1100,7,B^FS
^FO720,70^A0R,50,50^FDTest2^FS
^FB900,2,,
^FO600,70^A0R,50,50^FDTest Description^FS
^FO420,70^A0R,50,50^FDTest Lot^FS
^FO220,70^A0R,70,70^FDQty:^FS 
^FO 210,200^A0R,120,120^FD3^FS

^FO100,600^BQN,2,8^FDQ,Test2,Test Description,Test Lot
^XZ

Comment: Actually, we got the print with the expected size in one printer but when the printer changed this issue arose initial printer was ZP450 200dpi

Comment: Please print to a file instead of a printer to examine what bloats up the data.